# How to make drag and drop work running Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, windows-10, oracle, drag-and-drop

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 amd64 running in Oracle VM Virtual Box 5.1.6.

I have installed the Guest Additions CD.

Installed open-vm-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop however drag and drop from host (Windows 10 x64) to guest (Ubuntu Server amd64) does not work.

Reverse direction works (Ubuntu to Windows 10).

Shared clipboard works bi-directional.

What should I do to get drag and drop work bi-directional?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop is disabled by default.

It can be enabled once the VM is running at Devices > Drag and Drop.

Chose bidirectional or the option that best suits your needs (bidirectional, Host to Guest, Guest to Host).

Comment: I already have that setting enabled and set to bidirectional

Comment: @HamzaAhmedZia You can't drag and drop between different OS...it must be windows to windows or linux to linux  (host<->guest)

Comment: Nope @lewis4u I've seen it work with diff OS. I just can't get it work on my machine.

Comment: Ok i would like  to have that too if you find how to do it :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

**Setup:** I have installed Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.40 on my Windows 10 host. Running an Ubuntu 21.10 VM.

I have downloaded [VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.4.iso][1] and installed it in my Ubuntu VM. I verified the successful installation using the lsmod command.

I have set Drag&Drop=Bidirectional in the VB-->Device-->Drag&Drop